# finish multiple activities at once?

Tags: android, android-activity

When a user performs a task (indicated by T1 ~ T3), he eventually reaches activity `B`.

```
A->T1->T2-T3->B
Z->T2->T3->B (he could start from Z which is different from A, and can skip some activities such as T1)
```

At this point, I'd like to clear all the activities related to task T (T1 ~ T3).

I guess I can use subscriber-publisher pattern to send/listento `finish` message.

Are there a viable alternative?

Answer (score 2):

You can set Intent Flags. So when you start your new Activity, set the Flag to CLEAR_TOP, like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), A.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Then everything in the backstack until A (or Z) will be dropped. So When A would be your MainActivity, a back would make you exit the app.

You can read more on this here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How about the possibility of classes other than A (such as Z) could have started the task and I want to go back to Z if so?

Comment: I should know which activity started the task when I reach activity B. How should I do it?

Comment: When you come from A, start the next 'F'Actions in a new task using FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. Then when you start B, flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK combined with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. Hope that works ;-)